# Python Ctypes - unsigned char array as argument

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to use my lib from C in Python via Ctypes and I have problem with types in Ctypes

My C function have args:

```
fun(const char *something, const unsigned char *input, unsigned short val);
```

My problem is with  unsigned char *data. in C I'm passing an array:

```
unsigned char input_data[2] = {0x02, 0x01};
```

and then

```
fun(NULL,input_data,3);
```

and it's working. how to achieve that in python with ctypes? I tried in many ways, last one:

```
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.so')
lib.fun.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p, c_ushort)
input = (c_char_p * 2)(b'\x02',b'\x01')
lib.fun(c_char_p(None),input,c_ushort(2)))
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Looks like it should work, though overly complicated.  Last two lines can just be `lib.fun(None,b'\x02\x01',2)` since argtypes are declared.

Comment: I found issue, in argtype declaration there should be 'c_char_p * 2' as well...
    lib.fun.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p * 2, c_ushort)

Thank You for your time anyway